# Does "$\exists \delta >0$ S.T $||x(0)-x_e||<\delta\Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}||x(t)-x_e||=0$" imply stability?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Recall the definition of stable and Asymptotically stable:

1. A fixed point $x_e$ of a vector field is called (Lyapunov) stable if $\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta(\varepsilon)$ such that $\forall ||x(0)-x_e||<\delta \Rightarrow ||x(t)-x_e||<\varepsilon,\forall t\geq 0$
2. A fixed point $x_e$ of a vector field is called asymptotically stable if it's stable and the condition mentioned in the title "$\exists \delta >0$ S.T $||x(0)-x_e||<\delta\Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}=||x(t)-x_e||=0$"  is true.

So, my question is the that if the second condition in asymptotically stable implies stable? If not, what counter example can we take?

I guess the second condition doesn't imply stable. "stable" means I start my flow close to the fixed point $x_e$ and it will be **always** close but not necessarily convergent to $x_e$. And "asymptotically stable" means, besides the stability, the flow will not only be just close to $x_e$ but also converges to it in the end.

Thus, from this point of view, the second condition cannot imply "stable", because there definitely exists a flow that it will finally converge to $x_e$ but it won't necessarily be close to $x_e$ all the time, which means it might detour for a certain period and come back. However, I have hard time finding such flow.

I would really appreciate if you can help me find an example of such flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asymptotic stability is defined as Lyapunov stability plus the condition you cite; see, for example, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Definition_for_continuous-time_systems).

Under these definitions, asymptotic stability certainly implies Lyapunov stability, but not conversely. As a simple example, think of a trajectory that oscillates around $x_e$ with amplitude $\varepsilon/2$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

---

Edit: Ok, maybe my first reading didn't focus on the main issue of your question. Just because a trajectory limits to $x_e$ doesn't mean that it must "start close" (with a $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_e$) and "stay close" (in an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x_e$) *for all* $t\ge 0$.

Think of $f(t)=te^{-t}$ with $\varepsilon={1\over 10}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand what you said, but the answer somewhat deviated my question, because I was asking if "convergence(second condition of asymptotically stable) can imply stability" and the counter example for that.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps, I didn't make it clear. Simply speaking, "convergence+Lyapunov stable=asymtoptically stable" and my concern is if "convergence$\Rightarrow$ Lyapuno stable" is true.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to try to elucidate that part.

Comment: I perhaps have to make this as correct answer, because you might never believe that after I wrote $x=te^{-t}$ on my draft from your former advice and looked up your answer again, I saw!!! this coincidence made my day! :D Thanks for you help again.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not. Because stability means that we are *always* close to the equilibrium. It is a simple matter to present an example when it is true that
$$
\|x(t)-x_e\|\to 0
$$ 
for any initial conditions close enough to $x_e$, such that there are orbits that leave any small neighborhood of $x_e$.